# How can I filter a query with the results of a list?

Tags: soql, query

I want to search properties only from this one list, "HIP Prospects". If the name searched is in this list I want it to be returned. How can i achieve this?

Apex:

```
    public static List <Opportunity> searchName(String searchString) 
        {
            String searching = searchString + '%';
            List <Opportunity> returnList = new List <Opportunity> ();
            List <Opportunity> hipList = new List <Opportunity> ();
                hipList = [select Prop_Building_Name__r.name from opportunity
                  where recordtype.name in ('HIP Leasing Prospects')];

           //then i need to search hipList for the searchString
           new list<opportunity> qlist = [select Prop_Building_Name__r.name from hipList 
                                         where Prop_Building_Name__r.name=:searching];

           for (Opportunity opp: hipList) 
           {               
               returnList.add(opp);
           }
             return returnList;     
        }
```

or

```
public static List <Opportunity> searchName(String searchString) 
        {
            String searching = searchString + '%';
            List <Opportunity> returnList = new List <Opportunity> ();
            List <Opportunity> hipList = new List <Opportunity> ();
                hipList = [select Prop_Building_Name__r.name where 
                           Prop_Building_Name__r.name=:searching from opportunity];

           for (Opportunity opp: hipList) 
           {
               //how would i structure this
               if(opp.Prop_Building_Name__r.name is in ('HIP Leasing Prospects'))

               returnList.add(opp);
           }
             return returnList;     
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it as a criterion in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT ... FROM Opportunity WHERE ... AND Prop_Building_Name__r.name = :searching
```

Also, a lot of your code is just doing nothing at the expense of CPU cycles. Adding the records from one list to another is not necessary here. Just return the results of the query directly.

```
public static List <Opportunity> searchName(String searchString) 
{
    searchString = searchString + '%';
    return [
        SELECT Prop_Building_Name__r.Name FROM Opportunity
        WHERE Recordtype.Name = 'HIP Leasing Prospects'
        AND Prop_Building_Name__r.Name = :searchString
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was making this much more complicated than it needed to be. I have another question posted i dont know if you could help with or not.